# Lilypond keyboard diagrams

Tags: lilypond

Does Lilypond offers keyboard diagramms?

I've seen that there are guitar diagramms (aka [FretBoards](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/snippets/fretted-strings)). But I can not find something similar for keyboard/piano.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but we can draw them ourselves:

```
#(define (normalize-pitch-to-single-or-no-sharp p)
   (cond ((< (ly:pitch-alteration p) 0) ; raise flats
          (normalize-pitch-to-single-or-no-sharp (ly:pitch-transpose p (ly:make-pitch 0 -1 1/2))))
         ((or (> (ly:pitch-alteration p) 1/2) ; raise double sharps
              (and (> (ly:pitch-alteration p) 0) ; and single sharps for
                   (or (= (ly:pitch-notename p) 2) ; e
                       (= (ly:pitch-notename p) 6)))) ; b
          (normalize-pitch-to-single-or-no-sharp (ly:pitch-transpose p (ly:make-pitch 0 1 -1))))
         (else p)))

#(define (key-stencil length width bside blength bwidth bfac thickness fill)
   (cond ((not bside)
          (make-path-stencil
           `(
              moveto ,(/ thickness 2) ,(/ thickness -2)
              lineto ,(/ thickness 2) ,(- (/ thickness 2) length)
              lineto ,(- width (/ thickness 2)) ,(- (/ thickness 2) length)
              lineto ,(- width (/ thickness 2)) ,(/ thickness -2)
              closepath
            )
           thickness
           1 1 fill))
         ((< bside 0)
          (make-path-stencil
           `(
              moveto ,(/ thickness 2) ,(/ thickness -2)
              lineto ,(/ thickness 2) ,(- 0 (/ thickness 2) blength)
              lineto ,(- (/ thickness 2) (* bfac bwidth)) ,(- 0 (/ thickness 2) blength)
              lineto ,(- (/ thickness 2) (* bfac bwidth)) ,(- (/ thickness 2) length)
              lineto ,(- width (* bfac bwidth) (/ thickness 2)) ,(- (/ thickness 2) length)
              lineto ,(- width (* bfac bwidth) (/ thickness 2)) ,(/ thickness -2)
              closepath
            )
           thickness
           1 1 fill))
         ((> bside 0)
          (make-path-stencil
           `(
              moveto ,(/ thickness 2) ,(/ thickness -2)
              lineto ,(/ thickness 2) ,(- (/ thickness 2) length)
              lineto ,(- width (/ thickness 2)) ,(- (/ thickness 2) length)
              lineto ,(- width (/ thickness 2)) ,(- (/ thickness -2) blength)
              lineto ,(- width (* bfac bwidth) (/ thickness 2)) ,(- (/ thickness -2) blength)
              lineto ,(- width (* bfac bwidth) (/ thickness 2)) ,(/ thickness -2)
              closepath
            )
           thickness
           1 1 fill))
         (else
          (make-path-stencil
           `(
              moveto ,(/ thickness 2) ,(/ thickness -2)
              lineto ,(/ thickness 2) ,(- (/ thickness -2) blength)
              lineto ,(- (/ thickness 2) (* bfac bwidth)) ,(- (/ thickness -2) blength)
              lineto ,(- (/ thickness 2) (* bfac bwidth)) ,(- (/ thickness 2) length)
              lineto ,(- width (* bfac bwidth) (/ thickness 2)) ,(- (/ thickness 2) length)
              lineto ,(- width (* bfac bwidth) (/ thickness 2)) ,(- (/ thickness -2) blength)
              lineto ,(- width (* 2 bfac bwidth) (/ thickness 2)) ,(- (/ thickness -2) blength)
              lineto ,(- width (* 2 bfac bwidth) (/ thickness 2)) ,(/ thickness -2)
              closepath
            )
           thickness
           1 1 fill))))

#(define (bkey-stencil blength bwidth bfac thickness fill extrashift)
   (ly:stencil-translate-axis
    (make-path-stencil
      `(
        moveto ,(- (/ thickness 2) (* bfac bwidth)) ,(/ thickness -2)
        lineto ,(- (/ thickness 2) (* bfac bwidth)) ,(- (/ thickness 2) blength)
        lineto ,(- bwidth (* bfac bwidth) (/ thickness 2)) ,(- (/ thickness 2) blength)
        lineto ,(- bwidth (* bfac bwidth) (/ thickness 2)) ,(/ thickness -2)
        closepath
       )
      thickness
      1 1 fill)
    extrashift X))
    

#(define kbd-bside-map
   (list 1 0 -1 1 0 0 -1))

#(define (magstep->ss val layout)
   (let* ((base-font-size (ly:output-def-lookup layout 'text-font-size 11))
          (pt (* base-font-size (magstep val)))
          (rel-staff-space (ly:output-def-lookup layout 'staff-space 1))
          (base-staff-space (* 5 (/ base-font-size 11)))
          (fact (* rel-staff-space base-staff-space)))
     (/ pt fact)))

#(define (scaled-font-size val layout props)
   (let ((font-size (chain-assoc-get 'font-size props 0)))
     (magstep->ss (+ font-size (magnification->font-size val)) layout)))

#(define-markup-command (kbd-key layout props p) (ly:pitch?)
   #:properties ((thickness 0.1)
                 (keylength 3)
                 (bkeylength 2)
                 (keywidth 0.9)
                 (bkeywidth (* 0.9 2/3))
                 (bkeyfac 1/2)
                 (bkeyfill #t)
                 (shorten-bkey 0)
                 (thin-bkey 0)
                 (key-color #f)
                 (bkey-color #f)
                 (indicator-height 0.3)
                 (indicator-width 0.3)
                 (indicator-color #f)
                 (show-indicator #f)
                 (force-no-left-bside #f)
                 (force-no-right-bside #f))

   (let* ((p (normalize-pitch-to-single-or-no-sharp p))
          (nn (ly:pitch-notename p))
          (a (ly:pitch-alteration p)))
     (let* ((bside (list-ref kbd-bside-map nn))
            (bside (if force-no-left-bside
                       (cond ((< bside 0) #f)
                             ((= bside 0) RIGHT)
                             (else bside))
                       bside))
            (bside (if force-no-right-bside
                       (cond ((> bside 0) #f)
                             ((= bside 0) LEFT)
                             (else bside))
                       bside))
            (stc
             (if (> a 0)
                 (bkey-stencil
                  (- (scaled-font-size bkeylength layout props) shorten-bkey)
                  (- (scaled-font-size bkeywidth layout props) thin-bkey)
                  bkeyfac
                  thickness
                  (or bkeyfill bkey-color)
                  (- (/ thin-bkey 2)))
                 (key-stencil
                  (scaled-font-size keylength layout props)
                  (scaled-font-size keywidth layout props)
                  bside
                  (scaled-font-size bkeylength layout props)
                  (scaled-font-size bkeywidth layout props)
                  bkeyfac
                  thickness
                  key-color)))
            (stc (cond ((and (> a 0) bkey-color) (stencil-with-color stc bkey-color))
                       ((and (= a 0) key-color) (stencil-with-color stc key-color))
                       (else stc))))
       (if show-indicator
           (let* ((bside (or bside 0))
                  (w (scaled-font-size indicator-width layout props))
                  (h (scaled-font-size indicator-height layout props))
                  (ind (make-path-stencil
                        `(
                           moveto 0 ,(/ thickness 2)
                           lineto ,(- (/ w 2) (/ thickness 2)) ,(- h (/ thickness 2))
                           lineto ,(- (/ w -2) (/ thickness -2)) ,(- h (/ thickness 2))
                           closepath
                         )
                        thickness
                        1 1
                        indicator-color))
                  (iexty (ly:stencil-extent ind Y))
                  (ind (ly:make-stencil (ly:stencil-expr ind) '(0 . 0) iexty))
                  (ind (if indicator-color
                           (stencil-with-color ind indicator-color)
                           ind))
                  (x (interval-center (ly:stencil-extent stc X)))
                  (ind (ly:stencil-translate-axis ind x X))
                  (ind (ly:stencil-translate-axis
                        ind
                        (cond ((and (= a 0)
                                    (< bside 0))
                               (* bkeyfac (scaled-font-size bkeywidth layout props) 1/2))
                              ((and (= a 0)
                                    (> bside 0))
                               (* bkeyfac (scaled-font-size bkeywidth layout props) -1/2))
                              (else 0))
                        X)))
             (ly:stencil-add stc ind))
           stc))))

#(define-markup-command (draw-circle-scaled layout props radius thickness fill)
   (number? number? boolean?)
   (interpret-markup layout props
                     (markup #:draw-circle (scaled-font-size radius layout props) thickness fill)))

#(define-markup-command (vcenter-at-middle layout props mup) (markup?)
   (let ((stc (interpret-markup layout props mup))
         (em (cdr (ly:stencil-extent (interpret-markup layout props "M") Y))))
     (ly:stencil-translate-axis
      (ly:stencil-aligned-to stc Y CENTER)
      (/ em 2)
      Y)))

#(define-public (custom-note-name->markup pitch)
  (let ((str (note-name->string pitch)))
    (markup #:concat (
      (make-simple-markup (string-capitalize str))
      (make-vcenter-at-middle-markup
       ((@@ (lily) accidental->markup) (ly:pitch-alteration pitch)))))))

#(define-markup-command (kbd-key-with-marker layout props pitch) (ly:pitch?)
   #:properties ((marker-radius 0.3)
                 (marker-color "black")
                 (bmarker-color "white")
                 (bkeyfill #t)
                 (marker-as-text #f)
                 (marker-text #f)
                 (marker-key-color #f)
                 (marker-bkey-color #f)
                 (marker-hide-marker #f)
                 (thickness 0.1))
   (let* ((p (normalize-pitch-to-single-or-no-sharp pitch))
          (a (ly:pitch-alteration p))
          (key-stc
           (interpret-markup layout props
                             (if (and (> a 0) marker-bkey-color)
                                 (markup #:override (cons 'bkey-color marker-bkey-color)
                                         #:kbd-key p)
                                 (if (and (= a 0) marker-key-color)
                                     (markup #:override (cons 'key-color marker-key-color)
                                             #:kbd-key p)
                                     (markup #:kbd-key p))))))
     (if marker-hide-marker
         key-stc
         (let* ((marker-mup (if marker-as-text
                                (if marker-text
                                    marker-text
                                    (custom-note-name->markup pitch))
                                (markup #:draw-circle-scaled marker-radius 0 #t)))
                (marker-stc-r (interpret-markup layout props marker-mup))
                (f (/ (* (- (interval-length (ly:stencil-extent key-stc X)) (* 2 thickness)) 0.95)
                      (interval-length (ly:stencil-extent marker-stc-r X))))
                (marker-stc (interpret-markup layout props
                                              (markup #:fontsize (min (magnification->font-size f) 0)
                                                      marker-mup)))
                (marker-stc (if (and (> a 0) bkeyfill)
                                (ly:stencil-in-color marker-stc bmarker-color)
                                (ly:stencil-in-color marker-stc marker-color)))
                (x (interval-center (ly:stencil-extent key-stc X)))
                (y (+ (car (ly:stencil-extent key-stc Y))
                      (/ (max
                          (interval-length (ly:stencil-extent key-stc X))
                          (+ (* 2 thickness) (interval-length (ly:stencil-extent marker-stc Y))))
                         2)))
                (marker-stc
                 (ly:stencil-translate
                  (ly:stencil-aligned-to
                   (ly:stencil-aligned-to marker-stc X CENTER)
                   Y CENTER)
                  (cons x y))))
           (ly:stencil-add key-stc marker-stc))))) 


%\markup \override #'(marker-as-text . #t) \kbd-key-with-marker { c }
%\markup \kbd-key-with-marker { c }

%\markup \override #'(marker-as-text . #t) \kbd-key-with-marker { cis }
%\markup \kbd-key-with-marker { cis }

%\markup \override #'(marker-as-text . #t) \kbd-key-with-marker { cisis }
%\markup \kbd-key-with-marker { cisis }

#(define-markup-command (keyboard-stencil layout props pitches)
   ((lambda (x) (or (ly:music? x) (ly:pitch? x)
                    (and (list? x)
                         (fold (lambda (p prev) (and prev (ly:pitch? p))) #t x)))))
   #:properties ((keygap 0.05) (minsemitone #f) (maxsemitone #f)
                 (indicator-at #f)
                 (round-to-octaves #t)
                 (add-binding-line #f)
                 (thickness 0.1))
   (define (collapse idx p)
     (define (icollapse idx2 p2)
       (if (null? idx2)
           (cons (cons idx2 p2) '())
           (if (= (car idx) (car idx2))
               (let ((p (icollapse (cdr idx2) (cdr p2))))
                 (cons (car p) (cons (car p2) (cdr p))))
               (cons (cons idx2 p2) '()))))
     (if (null? idx)
         '()
         (let ((pair (icollapse idx p)))
           (cons (cons (car idx) (cdr pair))
                 (collapse (caar pair) (cdar pair))))))
   (define (create-marker-text ps)
     (markup #:override '(baseline-skip . 0)
             (make-column-markup (map (lambda (x) (custom-note-name->markup x)) ps))))
   (define (create-keyboard-stencils i min max map)
     (if (> i max)
         '()
         (let* ((p (normalize-pitch-to-single-or-no-sharp (ly:make-pitch 0 0 (/ i 2))))
                (m (if (and (not (null? map)) (= (caar map) i))
                       (markup #:override (cons 'marker-text (create-marker-text (cdar map)))
                               #:override (cons 'shorten-bkey keygap)
                               #:override (cons 'thin-bkey keygap)
                               #:kbd-key-with-marker p)
                       (markup #:override (cons 'shorten-bkey keygap)
                               #:override (cons 'thin-bkey keygap)
                               #:kbd-key p)))
                (m (if (and indicator-at (= indicator-at i))
                       (markup #:override '(show-indicator . #t) m)
                       m))
                (m (if (= i min)
                       (markup #:override '(force-no-left-bside . #t) m)
                       m))
                (m (if (= i max)
                       (markup #:override '(force-no-right-bside . #t) m)
                       m)))
           (cons (interpret-markup layout props m)
                 (create-keyboard-stencils (1+ i) min max
                                           (if (and (not (null? map)) (= (caar map) i))
                                               (cdr map)
                                               map))))))
   (define (stack-keys gap stcs carry i)
     (if (null? stcs)
         '()
         (cons (ly:stencil-translate-axis (car stcs) carry X)
               (stack-keys gap (cdr stcs)
                           (+ carry
                              (cdr (ly:stencil-extent (car stcs) X))
                              gap)
                           (1+ i)))))
   (let* ((pitches (cond ((ly:music? pitches)
                          (map (lambda (m) (ly:music-property m 'pitch))
                               (extract-named-music pitches 'NoteEvent)))
                         ((ly:pitch? pitches) (list pitches))
                         (else pitches)))
          (pitches (sort! pitches ly:pitch<?))
          (npitches (map ly:pitch-semitones pitches))
          (pitchmap (collapse npitches pitches))
          (mins (if (null? npitches) +inf.0 (first npitches)))
          (maxs (if (null? npitches) -inf.0 (last npitches)))
          (mins (if round-to-octaves (* (floor-quotient mins 12) 12) mins))
          (maxs (if round-to-octaves (1- (* (1+ (floor-quotient maxs 12)) 12)) maxs))
          (mins (if minsemitone (if (< minsemitone mins) minsemitone mins) mins))
          (maxs (if maxsemitone (if (> maxsemitone maxs) maxsemitone maxs) maxs))
          (stcs (create-keyboard-stencils mins mins maxs pitchmap))
          (stc (apply ly:stencil-add (stack-keys keygap stcs 0 mins)))
          (ext (ly:stencil-extent stc X))
          (stc (if add-binding-line
                   (ly:stencil-add
                    stc
                    (make-line-stencil thickness 
                                       (+ (car ext) (/ thickness 2))
                                       (/ thickness -2)
                                       (- (cdr ext) (/ thickness 2))
                                       (/ thickness -2)))
                   stc)))
     (ly:stencil-aligned-to stc Y DOWN)))

\markup\override #'(baseline-skip . 9) \column {
  \keyboard-stencil { c deses e g bes }
  
  \override #'((marker-as-text #t) (add-binding-line . #t))
  \keyboard-stencil { c deses e g bes }
  
  \override #'(bkeyfill . #f)
  \keyboard-stencil { c e g d'' fis'' }
  
  \override #'((marker-color . "blue") (bmarker-color . "red"))
  \fontsize #-3
  \keyboard-stencil { c e g d' fis' }
  
  \override #'((marker-color . "blue") (bmarker-color . "red"))
  \fontsize #-5
  \override #'(marker-as-text . #t)
  \keyboard-stencil { c e g d' fis' }
  
  \override #'((key-color . "lightgrey"))
  \keyboard-stencil { c e g d' fis' }
 
  \override #'((key-color . "lightgrey") (marker-key-color . "orange") (marker-bkey-color . "red")
               (add-binding-line #t))
  \keyboard-stencil { c e g d' fis' }
  
  \override #'((key-color . "lightgrey") (marker-key-color . "orange") (marker-bkey-color . "red")
               (marker-hide-marker . #t))
  \keyboard-stencil { c e g d' fis' }

  \override #'((key-color . "lightgrey") (marker-key-color . "orange") (marker-bkey-color . "red")
               (marker-hide-marker . #t) (minsemitone . 12) (maxsemitone . 23))
  \keyboard-stencil { c e g }

  \override #'((key-color . "lightgrey") (marker-key-color . "orange") (marker-bkey-color . "red")
               (marker-hide-marker . #t) (minsemitone . 12) (maxsemitone . 23)
               (indicator-at . 0))
  \keyboard-stencil { c e g }
  
  \override #'((key-color . "lightgrey") (marker-key-color . "orange") (marker-bkey-color . "red")
               (marker-hide-marker . #t) (minsemitone . 12) (maxsemitone . 23)
               (indicator-at . 0) (indicator-color . "green") (keygap . 0.1))
  \keyboard-stencil { c e g }
  
  \override #'((key-color . "lightgrey") (marker-key-color . "orange") (marker-bkey-color . "red")
               (marker-hide-marker . #t) (minsemitone . 12) (maxsemitone . 23)
               (indicator-at . 0) (indicator-color . "green") (keygap . 0.1)
               (keylength . 4) (bkeylength . 2.5)
               (indicator-height . 0.4) (indicator-width . 0.8))
  \keyboard-stencil { c e g }

  \keyboard-stencil { c }

  \keyboard-stencil #(list (ly:make-pitch 0 0) (ly:make-pitch 0 2) (ly:make-pitch 0 4))
  
  \override #`((minsemitone . ,(ly:pitch-semitones #{ a,,, #}))
               (maxsemitone . ,(+ 87 (ly:pitch-semitones #{ a,,, #}))))
  \keyboard-stencil { c g c' e' g' }
  
  \line { \keyboard-stencil { } "← empty" }
  
  \override #`((minsemitone . ,(ly:pitch-semitones #{ a,,, #}))
               (maxsemitone . ,(+ 87 (ly:pitch-semitones #{ a,,, #})))
               (add-binding-line #t))
  \keyboard-stencil { }
  
  \override #'((round-to-octaves . #f) (indicator-at . 0))
  \keyboard-stencil { a c' e' g' }
}
```

[image]

Comment: *If* you want another aspect of your code to work on, I'd suggest improving the displayed range.  

It'd be nice if you could optionally specify the highest and lowest keys shown, and if there was a parameter to show a full keyboard (88, 76, 61, 49, or 32 keys).

Comment: @ElementsinSpace If you inspect the code you will find there already is. See example 9! This code will use the minimum of full octaves (C-B) fitting the given notes. The parameters `minsemitone` and `maxsemitone` allow you to extend this range if given. A semitone is a enharmonic pitch representation of _semitone distance to c'_ where `c'` is 0, `cis'` or `des'` is 1 and so on. This can be obtained from a pitch by `(ly:pitch-semitones #{ as,, #})`. So if you want a keyboard of 88 keys starting at `a,,,` just do

Comment: @ElementsinSpace `\override #\`((minsemitone . ,(ly:pitch-semitones #{ a,,, #}))
               (maxsemitone . ,(+ 87 (ly:pitch-semitones #{ a,,, #}))))`

Comment: @ElementsinSpace The only problem here is that this will handle the bottom a and the top c as if they had a right / left black neighbor. I will fix this immediately!

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Done. I’ve also handled the case of no pitches given (empty stencil unless min max are given) and added a parameter to switch off the rounding to octaves (e.g. if you want to use a full keyboard you do not wand to extend to c,,, only because you use a,,,).

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Also added a parameter to draw a line over the top of the keys.

Comment: Ah, yes. It's working well now. This is awesome!  

(Now you just need to get it to process sequences of music into an animation, haha!)

Comment: @Simply add an engraver that collects all notes, draws diagrams and add pagebreaks. Then you just need to switch the frame at the right time.

Comment: @Lazy On the one the question has been answered. On the other side there is a very interesting, useful and beautiful piece of code. Chapeau!

Comment: @Lazy Did you considered to upload the code to github or similar? One extension of the code could be to add fingerings.